# Zeroes of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $\mathcal{O} = \{z: f$ has zero of order $\infty$$\}$. We claim that $\mathcal{O}$ is open. To prove this we note that, if $f$ has a zero of infinite order at $z_{0}$, then all the Taylor co-efficients at $z_{0}$ vanish and $f$ is $0$ on a whole neighbourhood of $z_{0}$. I understand that having a zero of infinite order would mean that all the taylor co-efficients vanish because the function has $z_{0}$ as a root repeated infinite times, but I don't understand why $f$ being $0$ on a  whole nbd would imply that $\mathcal{O}$ is open.

EDIT: $f$ as defined above is always assumed to be a holomorphic function

Comment: Because neighbourhoods are always open?

Comment: The more interesing part is why zero Taylor series imlpies zero in a naighbourhood. You may want to add that your functions should be anylatic or such

Comment: yes sorry, i edited it now

Comment: @HarryWilson: Neighbourhoods aren't always open. What's true (and useful here) is that a set is open iff it is a neighbourhood of every point in it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ to be a holomorphic (or analytic) function, and $\mathcal{O} = \{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid f \text{ has a zero of order } \infty \text{ at } z\} $.

You know that, for each $z \in \mathcal{O}$, there exists a neighborhood $U_{z}$ of $z$ such that $U_{z} \subseteq \mathcal{O}$. Now clearly

$$ \bigcup_{z \in \mathcal{O}} U_z \subseteq \mathcal{O} \subseteq \bigcup_{z \in \mathcal{O}} U_z,$$
which implies that $\mathcal{O} = \bigcup_{z \in \mathcal{O}} U_z$. Now the latter set is clearly open (why?), and so is $\mathcal{O}$.

EDIT: One important piece of the puzzle is the following:

> $z \in \mathcal{O}$ if and only if there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $z$ where $f$ is identically zero.

$f \equiv 0$ on $U$ implies that $f^{(n)}(z) = 0$ for each $n$, so that $z$ is a zero of order $\infty$. Conversely, if $z$ is a zero of order $\infty$, it vanishes in a neighborhood (by Taylor).